# Display image based on category

Tags: wordpress, image, categories

I'm using Wordpress for my blog (blog.axelboberg.se), I wish to show an icon just over each title. The icon should be based and display the posts category. I've heard that it's possible to use an if statement, but that gets tricky when using more categories/images?

How do I display an image over each title based on the category? I'm planning to use 3-4 different icons.

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0):

In the category.php file add

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach($categories as $category) 
{
    if($category->cat_name == "category1")
    {
        echo '<img src="">';
    }
    else if ($category->cat_name == "category2")
    {
        echo '<img src="">';
    }
}
?>
```

just above this line:

```
<h1 class="archive-title"><?php printf( __( 'Category Archives: %s', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
```

The above will only print out an image if it is on a specific category

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find the line that starts with h1 in my category.php file...